# How to compact / shrink a Dynamically Allocated virtual box vmdk file on a ubuntu guest after deleting a bunch of files?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a very old virtual box with ubuntu 14 guest installed. Its currently taking up over 50GB and I just deletect 35GB of data on this virtualbox, but since the hard drive is **Dynamically allocated** the vmdk file is still its original huge size. What is an easy way to compact / shrink this vmdk file? I'm on Windows 10 as host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The virtual disk image is a `VMDK` file or `VDI` file?

`VBoxManage` only shrinks `VDI` file based disk images.

To do that...

First, zero fill your virtual disk. Boot the VM and run:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/bigemptyfile bs=4096k status=progress
sudo rm -f /bigemptyfile
```

Shut down the VM and VirtualBox.

Then on the host run:

```
vboxmanage modifymedium x:\path\to\disk.vdi --compact
```

**Note**: You'll have to specify the path of `vboxmanage` (generally '`C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`').

Comment: its my **vmdk** file that is over 50GB. so i'm out of luck?

Comment: You can convert `VMDK` to `VDI` using the command: `vboxmanage clonehd --format VDI x:\path\to\disk.vmdk x:\path\to\disk.vdi`

Comment: Does zero fill my virtual disk would require me to fill it up to my max capacity of 500GB? that is what I have set. But my SSD is only 500GB and I only have 20gb free right now.

Comment: screenshot: http://prntscr.com/klgl74

Comment: After zero filling, remove/delete the `/bigemptyfile`, shutdown the VM and then compact the disk.

Comment: doesn't clonehd command makes a copy of my vmdk file? which means its 2x50GB = 100GB of free space I need right?

Comment: Yes, it does, but once it gets converted (and it works properly) you can compact it and then delete the `VMDK`, retaining the `VDI`.

Comment: @kanchu, the syntax changed slightly over the time, now it's: `vboxmanage clonemedium disk x:\path\to\disk.vmdk x:\path\to\disk.vd --format VDI`